# how to Solve 'Credential' isn't defined for the type 'FacebookAuthProvider'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i am using this code that i got from github :

**code from github:**

```
Future<FirebaseUser> facebookLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    try {
      final FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult =
          await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
      if (facebookLoginResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
        FacebookAccessToken facebookAccessToken =
            facebookLoginResult.accessToken;
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
        FirebaseUser user = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
        print("signed in" + user.displayName);
        return user;

      }
```

i got 2 errors from the above code:

> error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. (not_enough_positional_arguments at [flutter_app] lib\login_page.dart:31)

> error: The named parameter 'accessToken' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [flutter_app] lib\login_page.dart:32)

as far as i understand the "FirebaseUser" and the "getCredential" are depreciated so i changed them to User and Credential :
current code :

```
  Future<User> facebookLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    User currentUser;

    // fbLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
    // if you remove above comment then facebook login will take username and pasword for login in Webview
    try {
      final FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult =
      await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
      if (facebookLoginResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
        FacebookAccessToken facebookAccessToken =
            facebookLoginResult.accessToken;
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.Credential(
            accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
        User user = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
        print("signed in" + user.displayName);
        return user;
      }
```

but now i am getting the error :

> error: The method 'Credential' isn't defined for the type 'FacebookAuthProvider'. (undefined_method at [flutter_app] lib\login_page.dart:33)

did i made a mistake in changing the FirebaseUser to User and getCredential to Credential?
how to get out of this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spelling is `credential` with a lowercase `c`. So:

```
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
```

For situations like this, I find the documentation most helpful: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FacebookAuthProvider-class.html